# Getting error messages in tester...5/8 correct

Tags: python, testing, filter, triggers, counter

I am running a function that filters stories and returns the number of filtered stories. The code is below - and the errors in the tests are below that. The errors seem to just give a miscount in the number of filter stories that are counted - simple error but have been having problems trying solve it. The numbers of filtered stories does not match. Please help.

My code:

```
def filterStories(stories, triggerlist):

   newstories = []
   for story in stories:
       for trigger in triggerlist:
           if trigger.evaluate(story) == True:
               newstories.append(story)

       stories = newstories
   return stories

class WordTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self,word):
        self.word = word.lower()

    def changeChars(self,text):
        final = ""
        for c in text:
            if c in string.punctuation:
                final += " "
            else:
                final += c
        return final

    def isWordIn(self,text):
        comp = self.changeChars(text)
        list = comp.lower().split(" ")
        return self.word in list

# TODO: TitleTrigger
class TitleTrigger(WordTrigger):
    def evaluate(self,story):
        return self.isWordIn(story.getTitle())

# TODO: SubjectTrigger
class SubjectTrigger(WordTrigger):
    def evaluate(self,story):
        return self.isWordIn(story.getSubject())

# TODO: SummaryTrigger
class SummaryTrigger(WordTrigger):
    def evaluate(self,story):
        return self.isWordIn(story.getSummary())

class PhraseTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self,phrase):
        self.phrase = phrase

    def evaluate(self,story):
        return self.phrase in story.getTitle() or self.phrase in story.getSubject() or self.phrase in story.getSummary()
```

-----------------ERROR MESSAGES FROM TESTS-------------------------------------------------

```
Test: filterStories 3
Your output:
Trigger 1: TrueTrigger() - always returns True
Trigger 2: TrueTrigger() - always returns True
Story with title: "MIT and Russia Partner with Skolkovo Tech" and subject: "New school located near Moscow"
In filteredStories?  True
Story with title: "Russian dignitaries Visit USA" and subject: "Obama meets with Russian President Vladimir Putin"
In filteredStories?  True
Story with title: "Russia Overrun With Friendly Tigers" and subject: "Putin poses for photo op with cuddly felines"
In filteredStories?  True
Story with title: "Mitt Romney Defeated" and subject: "Obama edges win over Republican challenger Mitt Romney"
In filteredStories?  True
Number of filtered stories:  8
Story titles in the list of filtered stories your code generated:
['MIT and Russia Partner with Skolkovo Tech', 'MIT and Russia Partner with Skolkovo Tech', 'Mitt Romney Defeated', 'Mitt Romney Defeated', 'Russia Overrun With Friendly Tigers', 'Russia Overrun With Friendly Tigers', 'Russian dignitaries Visit USA', 'Russian dignitaries Visit USA']
Correct output:
Trigger 1: TrueTrigger() - always returns True
Trigger 2: TrueTrigger() - always returns True
Story with title: "MIT and Russia Partner with Skolkovo Tech" and subject: "New school located near Moscow"
In filteredStories?  True
Story with title: "Russian dignitaries Visit USA" and subject: "Obama meets with Russian President Vladimir Putin"
In filteredStories?  True
Story with title: "Russia Overrun With Friendly Tigers" and subject: "Putin poses for photo op with cuddly felines"
In filteredStories?  True
Story with title: "Mitt Romney Defeated" and subject: "Obama edges win over Republican challenger Mitt Romney"
In filteredStories?  True
Number of filtered stories:  4
Story titles in the list of filtered stories your code generated:
['MIT and Russia Partner with Skolkovo Tech', 'Mitt Romney Defeated', 'Russia Overrun With Friendly Tigers', 'Russian dignitaries Visit USA']
Test: filterStories 4
Your output:
Trigger 1: TitleTrigger("Russia")
Trigger 2: SubjectTrigger("Putin")
Trigger 3: TitleTrigger("MIT")
Story with title: "MIT and Russia Partner with Skolkovo Tech" and subject: "New school located near Moscow"
In filteredStories?  True
Story with title: "Russian dignitaries Visit USA" and subject: "Obama meets with Russian President Vladimir Putin"
In filteredStories?  True
Story with title: "Russia Overrun With Friendly Tigers" and subject: "Putin poses for photo op with cuddly felines"
In filteredStories?  True
Story with title: "Mitt Romney Defeated" and subject: "Obama edges win over Republican challenger Mitt Romney"
In filteredStories?  False
Number of filtered stories:  5
Story titles in the list of filtered stories your code generated:
['MIT and Russia Partner with Skolkovo Tech', 'MIT and Russia Partner with Skolkovo Tech', 'Russia Overrun With Friendly Tigers', 'Russia Overrun With Friendly Tigers', 'Russian dignitaries Visit USA']
Correct output:
Trigger 1: TitleTrigger("Russia")
Trigger 2: SubjectTrigger("Putin")
Trigger 3: TitleTrigger("MIT")
Story with title: "MIT and Russia Partner with Skolkovo Tech" and subject: "New school located near Moscow"
In filteredStories?  True
Story with title: "Russian dignitaries Visit USA" and subject: "Obama meets with Russian President Vladimir Putin"
In filteredStories?  True
Story with title: "Russia Overrun With Friendly Tigers" and subject: "Putin poses for photo op with cuddly felines"
In filteredStories?  True
Story with title: "Mitt Romney Defeated" and subject: "Obama edges win over Republican challenger Mitt Romney"
In filteredStories?  False
Number of filtered stories:  3
Story titles in the list of filtered stories your code generated:
['MIT and Russia Partner with Skolkovo Tech', 'Russia Overrun With Friendly Tigers', 'Russian dignitaries Visit USA']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add in your function `filterstories` the following test before inserting your story into the `filterlist`:

```
   for trigger in triggerlist:
       if trigger.evaluate(story) == True:
           if story not in newstories:
               newstories.append(story)

   stories = newstories
```

Should work.

In fact you are duplicating entries which is causing your test to fail.